# Ошибки компиляции из командной строки: Error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!

У меня такая проблема: при компиляции программы в Eclipse все проходит успешно и запускается. А если компилировать с командной строки, то до запуска не доходит из-за кучи подобных ошибок:

[image]

Что нужно поправить, что бы скомпилировать успешно ?

Comment: а строка компиляции где?

Comment: javac MainWindow.java

Comment: добавьте classpath, где лежат класcы SettingsWindows, FieldPanel, FieldCalculator

Comment: как всегда в таких случаях отправляю к [Skipy](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/likbez.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пропишите корректный `classpath`. Компилятор не видит не библиотеки, в которых у вас лежат эти классы. Сделать это можно опцией компилятора `cp` и указанием `*jar` файлов или директорий. Пример:

```
javac -cp lib1.jar:lib2.jar:lib3.jar:/lib/dir/:../:. MainWindow.java
```

Используемые бибилиотеки можно посмотреть в проекте Eclipse.

Делать это нужно, даже если вы используете самописные классы, в таком случае нужно указать все директории (или запакованные `.jar` файлы) в которых у вас лежат скомпилированные `.class` файлы.

Comment: ух, не знал про двоеточие, всегда ; отделял библиотеки, спасибо